# How to CI-CD a windows installer? I want the deployment to place the .msi in a specific location

Tags: windows-installer, continuous-deployment

I want to create CI-CD pipeline in Azure DevOps for a Winform application which has an installer. I want my CD to put the .msi / .exe in the specified location / drop folder with the latest after every check-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WiX Toolset](https://wixtoolset.org) was tailor-made for this scenario. Add a .wixproj to your solution, write the installation code and it will just work in Azure DevOps. It even works in Hosted Azure DevOps builds because the WiX Toolset is part of their images.

The WiX Toolset is powerful and you can read more about it in [the tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

I used Advanced Installer packaging tool and this is very easy to integrate with Azure DevOps continuous delivery. Here is a small step-by-step article describing how you can configure an installer continuous delivery:

[Advanced Installer for Azure DevOps (VSTS)](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-vsts-integration.html)

Also, you can easily integrate Advanced Installer with your Visual Studio solution by using their [Advanced Installer extension for Visual Studio](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-ai-ext-vs.html).